# Compare hardcoded date with the current date

Tags: javascript, date

I am trying to compare dates in javascript.
I have a hardcoded date (03/23/2015 11:20 am) in  of , and I am trying to compare it with the current date in the same format.
But I am always getting it as not same.

```js
function formatDate(date) {
    var hours = date.getHours();
    var minutes = date.getMinutes();
    var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';
    hours = hours % 12;
    hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
    minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes;
    var strTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + ampm;
    return date.getMonth() + 1 + "/" + date.getDate() + "/" + date.getFullYear() + "  " + strTime;

}

var d = new Date();
var timeNow = formatDate(D);
var startTime6 = document.getElementById('tno6_time').innerHTML;
if (timenow == startTime6) {
    alert("Same");
}
else {
    alert("not same");
}
```

Comment: Try this plugin out - https://code.google.com/p/datejs/

Comment: Why would the current date be equal to a hard coded date?

Comment: @Vaishnavi What is the value of "startTime6" variable ?

Comment: @SatyamKoyani current hard coded date. Format ---> 03/23/2015 11:48 am

Answer (score 1):

Your's javascript portion :

```
var d = new Date();
var timeNow = formatDate(D);
if (timenow == startTime6) {
    alert("Same");
}
```

Here check in above code you are creating variable with name **d** and you are passing variable **D** which is not declared.Here you have also typo in **timeNow** not **timenow**.It should be like

```
var timeNow = formatDate(d);
if (timeNow == startTime6) {
    alert("Same");
}
```

Apart from that check both the variables value either with **console.log()**  function or with **alert()** and see if there are same then It should alert the 'Same' else 'not same'.

And keep in mind `new Date()` will always give you current time so if you are comparing with hard coded date then Only once there are the possibility that result should come 'Same' and It will only occur when you are executing this code when the hard coded date and time exactly the same.

It is very hard to check your code in that way because millisecond change will affect your result.

[Check this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/742dvoxe/2/)

Comment: Hi,I tried with d only, but that is not the issue.
I tried displaying the dates with alert, both current and hardcoded date are in the same format (03/23/2015 11:48 am).
I have taken the format in which millisecond is not considered.

Comment: @Vaishnavi It was one issue. Same typing mistake in "timenow". Check my edited answer again and see the demo fiddle.You can get more details from  that.

Comment: Is there any way to omit milliseconds and compare..?